# How to count number of rows based on values in other columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, count

Having a dataset like this:

```
Ln_id  Pl_id    No_Flag  Nrs     Rms
------ -------- -------- ------- ------
343    122127   0        22.45   23.16
343    211238   0        18.02   12.90
343    187621   0        79.87   24.95
...
```

So given this structure of a table, how do I count every single record that matches this pattern of having the same `Ln_id`, different `Pl_id`'s and with `No_Flag` set to 0.

So the 3 rows up there would count as 'a' record.
How do you actually solve this?

This is strictly Oracle.

Comment: What if there were a 4th record with ln_id = 343, no_flag = 0, and pl_id = 122127 again.  How should that be counted?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
with t(Ln_id,  Pl_id,  No_Flag,    Nrs ,    Rms) as 
(
select 343,    122127, 0 ,         22.45  , 23.16 from dual union all
select 343 ,   211238 ,0  ,        18.02,   12.90 from dual union all
select 343  ,  187621, 0       ,   79.87  , 24.95 from dual)
--sample data
select ln_id,count(*) from t
where no_flag = 0 
group by ln_id
```